# How to setup a Helm Registry on JFrog Artifactory? Can we use cm-push plugin to push helm charts to JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, artifactory

I am faced with a situation where I need to use JFrog Artifactory as a Helm Registry. I have got the Helm Chart ready with me and have added the Helm Repo using the helm repo add command. However, while trying to push the chart to JFrog Registry. I am faced with the error - 404 unable to pass JSON.

Can we use JFrog Remote Repositories as Helm Registries? If yes can someone point towards the working JFrog Docs?

Currently, I am using the helm cm-push plugin to push the chart.tgz files to registry. This is working if I want to push to Gitlab Registry but doesn't seem to be working for Artifactory Repo. Can we use cm-push plugin to push to JFrog Helm Registry?

Comment: What type of repository is created on Artifactory? A correct flow requires the creation of a remote Repository with repoType Helm (proxy and cache).
Take a look here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/kubernetes-helm-chart-repositories

Answer (score 1):

So first lets clarify the following helm supports helm-chart repositories [(repository docs)](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_repository/) as well as the so called the oci-based registries [registry docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/).

Jfrog artifactory supports both.

The first is supported through the so called "Kubernetes Helm Chart Repositories" [docs](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/kubernetes-helm-chart-repositories). This type is supported from all versions of the helm you can push there either by `curl` or the `jf` cli tool.

The sesond is supported through the artifactory docker registry [(docs)](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/docker-registry) the reigstry is oci-compliant so you can push there helm-charts as well. For that you can use the native `helm push` command. For helm >= 3.8.

Both type of repositories support remote repositories/registries.

If the above are not clear enough feel free to come back for examples.

So an example for the oci-registry would look like [(also docs)](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/#the-registry-subcommand)

```
helm registry login -u jfroguser my-artifactory.int:5000
helm push mychart-0.1.0.tgz oci://my-artifactory.int:5000/helm-charts
```

Comment: Hi @zochamx. Thanks for the explanation. Can you point me to example articles following the 2nd approach?

Comment: Hi @Mayank I updated the answer with an example from the docs.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. 

`$ helm repo list`
`NAME            URL`
`helm            https://rathoremayank.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/helm/helm`

`$ helm registry login -u career.mayankrathore@gmail.com -p <password> oci://rathoremayank.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/helm/`

`WARNING: Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.`
`INFO[0000] Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint  error="Get` `\"https://oci/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup oci on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host"`
`Error: Get "https://oci/v2/": dial tcp: lookup oci on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host`
`$`
`

Comment: Is it true that JFrog doesnt support any native helm push plugins?

Comment: You are trying to push to an artifactory helm repository. That is not possible with helm push. Create an artifactory docker registry and try to push there.

Comment: I want to use Artifactory Repo as the helm repo.

Comment: The approach you chose is to use the artifactory registry as a helm repository. If you have a working docker registry in artifactory you can `helm push` there your helm charts.